# Confused about returns in stack template

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I'm implementing a generic stack (with an array) in C++ and am confused about what to return in this situation:

```
template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop(void) {
    if (size != 0) {
        return items[size - 1];
        size--;
    } else {
        cerr << "Cannot pop from empty stack." << endl;
        return ???;
    }
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::peek(void) {
    if (size != 0)
        return items[size - 1];
    else {
        cerr << "Cannot peek from empty stack." << endl;
        return ???;
    }
}
```

What are my options here? I think it would be messy to do something like declaring a new T variable and returning it. I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: throw an exception?

Comment: note : statements after a `return` are unreachable - specifically, the `size--;` line will not be run !

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Yeah that was an accident. Already fixed it

Comment: The `std` implementation throws an exception, you could also return a `pair` with a `bool` for success and the actual element (default constructed if empty). Also, don't use an array, use a `vector` or a `deque`

Comment: @imreal. That forces T to be default constructable even in cases where the users of the container doesn't make this mistake. Maybe return a `pair<bool, optional<T>>` or similar.

Comment: Thanks @MikeVine. For some reason I thought I still needed to return after throwing an exception.

Comment: @imreal and MikeVine: I have a constructor that takes nothing (I think that's what you mean by default constructible) that creates the array of size 0, but would need to be changed later with setSize(). I also have a constructor that takes a size... Is this bad practice?

Comment: @JoseMagana The "default constructible" requirement induced by the `std::pair` option is for `T`, not for `Stack<T>`.

Comment: @MikeVine You're right, an `optional` would be better, and eliminate the need of the `pair`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on what you want the behaviour (protocol) of your class to be. Since you're logging into the error stream there, I assume you consider this an error condition to call `pop()` on an empty stack. The standard C++ way of signalling errors is to throw an exception. Something like this:

```
template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop(void) {
    if (size != 0) {
        size--;
        return items[size];
    } else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Cannot pop from empty stack.");
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to say that `pop()` has a *precondition* "stack is not empty." Violation of a precondition is generally undefined behaviour, so you could simply assume the stack is not empty. This is the useful approach for performance-critical code:

```
template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop(void) {
    asssert(size > 0);  // not necessary, but it's good practice to assert preconditions
    size--;
    return items[size];
}
```

---

The above two approaches assume that calling `pop()` on an empty stack is an error, i.e. that it shouldn't happen. If you instead want that to be a valid operation with a well-defined result, you have a few other options.

Return a flag indicating success:

```
template <class T>
std::pair<T, bool> Stack<T>::pop(void) {
    if (size != 0) {
        size--;
        return std::make_pair(items[size], true);
    } else {
        return std::make_pair(T(), false);  // requires T to be default-constructible
    }
}
```

Return a [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html):

```
template <class T>
boost::optional<T> Stack<T>::pop(void) {
    if (size != 0) {
        size--;
        return items[size];
    } else {
        return boost::none;
    }
}
```

Return a default-constructed `T`:

```
template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop(void) {
    if (size != 0) {
        size--;
        return items[size];
    } else {
        return T();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually in such situations an exception is thrown.

Or you should change the return type of function `pop` to `void`.

As for the function `peak` then it could return a reference to an object in the stack.